# PHP class: referenced variable in one method affects non-referenced variable in other method

Tags: php, class, properties, scope, reference

I'm puzzled by the behaviour in the following example. I stumbled over this in a project and it took me hours to narrow the problem down to a simple example. So this is my simple test class:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public $sess = [['name' => 'John']];

    public function info() {
        $this->runTest();
        echo $this->sess[0]['name'];
    }

    private function runTest() {
        $localSess = &$this->sess[0];
        $this->sessTest();
    }

    private function sessTest() {
        $sessCopy = $this->sess;
        $this->sess[0]['name'] = 'Bob';
        $this->sess = $sessCopy;
    }
}

$myFoo = new Foo;
$myFoo->info();
```

The unexpected resulting output is:

> Bob

If `$localSess` is just a simple assignment and not a reference, the output is (as expected): `John`

I don't understand what's going on here. Since the class property `$sess` is an array and not an object, the assignment to `$sessCopy` should be a simple copy. But if you print the content of `$sessCopy` right after modifying `$this->sess`, it will contain the changed value for 'name'. So it seems as if `$sessCopy` were a reference after all? But only if `$localSess` in the calling method is a reference. Why should that even matter? BTW, if `$localSess` is a reference to the whole array of the class property and not just to its first index, everything works as expected.

Can someone please shed some light on this? If the mere existence of a variable reference in one function can influence the content of a local variable (not a reference!) in another function, then that seems dangerous and scary.

Comment: Huh. It seems to affect only [array elements](https://3v4l.org/7IAse). Now I'm really curious.

Comment: Investigating further revealed that referencing an array element will make the array hold the reference, so any further attempts to copy the array will [work with the reference](https://3v4l.org/Y9bVd).

Comment: Though note that copying the element directly [does not pick up the reference](https://3v4l.org/TTJaU).

Comment: Here, found something in the [doc comments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php#79220).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I decided to create a simpler example that illustrates the same problem:

```
$a = [['name' => 'John']];
$b = $a; // makes a copy of `$a`
$b[0]['name'] = "Bob";
echo $a[0]['name]; // returns "John" as expected
```

However if you did:

```
$a = [['name' => 'John']];
/* var_dump($a) returns:
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "John"
  }
}
*/
$local = &$a[0]; // seems to modify $a[0], so its type &array
/* var_dump($a) returns:
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  &array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "John"
  }
}
*/
$b = $a; // makes a copy of `$a`
$b[0]['name'] = "Bob";
echo $a[0]['name]; // returns "Bob"
```

This behaviour I admit is odd, but is documented in multiple PHP doc comments:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php#79220
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php#102123
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php#79220

It turns out this is actually a PHP bug first reported in 2000:

- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=20993
- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=6417
- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=7412
- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=15025

There was supposed to be updates to the documentation but I could not find it:

> Due to peculiarities of the internal workings of  PHP, if a reference is made to a single element of an array and then the
> array is copied, whether by assignment or when passed by value in a
> function call, the reference is copied as part of the array.  This
> means that changes to any such elements in either array will be
> duplicated in the other array (and in the other references), even
> if the arrays have different scopes (e.g. one is an argument
> inside a function and the other is global)!  Elements that did not have
> references at the time of the copy, as well as references assigned to
> those other elements after the copy of the array, will behave
> normally (i.e.  independent of the other array).

However, it has been marked as `Wont fixed`, likely due to performance reasons.
Notable comments:

> We have discussed this issue and it will put a considerable slowdown on php's performance, to fix this properly.
>
> Therefore this behaviour will be documented.

Even though it was never documented.

I have decided to raise another bug report on this issue to see if the position on this issue has changed.

I have now re-reported the issue:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80955

### Solutions

One workaround is:

```
$b = unserialize(serialize($a));
```

Another is:

```
function array_clone($array) {
    return array_map(function($element) {
        if ((is_array($element))) {
            return array_clone($element);
        } else if (is_object($element)) {
            return clone $element;
        } else {
            return $element;
        }
    }, $array);
}

$b = array_clone($a);
```

Comment: Odd is quite the understatement IMHO, and documented in a doc comment, oh my...

Comment: I re-reported the issue: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80955 . Let's see what they say.

Comment: Your simplified example certainly helps to further ilIustrate the problem. But at least everything is in the same scope there. (Don't get me wrong: it's still highly counter-intuitive and feels buggy.) But once your variables live in different scopes, you kinda don't know what hit you, With OOP you might not even know what goes on in the method that called your method.
I guess the lesson here is: don't do references to array elements, particularly if those arrays are global or global in nature (ie. properties within your class).

Comment: @Stoppeye yes agreeed

Comment: Or you could use one of the workarounds. Not great, but usable.